# How to cache infrequently changing mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql query that is taking 8 seconds to execute/fetch (in workbench).

I won't go into the details of why it may be slow (I think `GROUPBY` isnt helping though).

What I really want to know is, how I can basically cache it to work more quickly because the tables only change like 5-10 times/hr, while users access the site 1000s times/hour.

Is there a way to just have the results regenerated/cached when the db changes so results are not constantly regenerated?

I'm quite new to sql so any basic thought may go a long way.

Comment: If you have direct access to the config of your mysql database, you could check if `Query Cache` ([How the Query Cache Operates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html)) is active and if you could optimize this for your use case. Another way to reduce mysql calls is to cache the result in your application, that way you - depending on the use case - could also cache the post processing that is done with the result. (Personally i prefere the second one, because i have more control about how and where the data is cached).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with such a caching facility in MySQL.  There are alternatives.

One mechanism would be to use application level caching.  The application would store the previous result and use that if possible.  Note this wouldn't really work well for multiple users.

What you might want to do is store the report in a separate table.  Then you can run that every five minutes or so.  This would be a simple mechanism using a job scheduler to run the job.

A variation on this would be to have a stored procedure that first checks if the data has changed.  If the underlying data has changed, then the stored procedure would regenerate the report table.  When the stored procedure is done, the report table would be up-to-date.

An alternative would be to use triggers, whenever the underlying data changes.  The trigger could run the query, storing the results in a table (as above).  Alternatively, the trigger could just update the rows in the report that would have changed (harder, because it involves understanding the business logic behind the report).

All of these require some change to the application.  If your application query is stored in a view (something like `vw_FetchReport1`) then the change is trivial and all on the server side.  If the query is embedded in the application, then you need to replace it with something else.  I strongly advocate using views (or in other databases user defined functions or stored procedures) for database access.  This defines the API for the database application and greatly facilitates changes such as the ones described here.

EDIT: (in response to comment)

More information about scheduling jobs in MySQL is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-overview.html).  I would expect the SQL code to be something like:

```
truncate table ReportTable;

insert into ReportTable
    select * from <ReportQuery>;
```

(In practice, you would include column lists in the `select` and `insert` statements.)

Comment: i am using a "routine" in the db. not interested in application level changes.  but could you elaborate on the how i could run the query every 5 minutes and store the result in a separate table.  do you literally just mean that i should create a new table entirely?  if so is there a way to make it read only once created?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that can be used to speed-up the response time for long running queries is to periodically generate summarized tables, based on underlying data refreshing or business needs.

For example, if your business don't care about sub-minute "accuracy", you can run the process once each minute and make your user interface to query this calculated table, instead of summarizing raw data online.